# How to wait() in a REST web service using Java and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, wait

I'm working on a Spring Boot microservice and this microservice communicates with another microservice to receive some data using REST. Something like that:

```
public class PdfClient {

    private ErternMicr externMicr;

    @Autowired
    public PdfClient(ErternMicr externMicr) {
        this.externMicr = externMicr;
    }

    public String getData(String pdfId) {
        String pdf = "0";
        pdf = externMicr.getPdfData(pdfId);
        return pdf;
    }
}
```

So when this `externMicr.getPdfData(pdfId)` is called I get some data from another microservice using REST. What I need to do is I don't want to wait long time to receive the data, I want to call this method 3 times for 10 seconds each time and if the data do not come in this period of time, the return will be "0". How can I do that? Any feedback will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please check if CompleteableFuture can help.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this, you can try using a Executor from the concurrent package:

```
final ExecutorService restService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

try {
     final Future<String> pdfFuture = restService.submit(() -> {
         // PUT YOUR PDF CODE HERE
         return pdf;
     });

     String pdfFile = pdfFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (final TimeoutException e) {
    // TIMEOUT!
    return "0";
} finally {
    restService.shutdown();
}
```

You can use this as the basis of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for reply! So I need to put the externMicr.getPdfData(pdfId) instead of // PUT YOUR PDF CODE HERE, but how could I repeat this method call 3 times if I don't receive the data in 10 seconds for every call.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a very simple thing you're trying to achieve, just use what @dacuna explained in his reply.

But if you're worried the external microservice may take too long to respond too many times, or you want to cover your back against possible outages, or get into a cascading failure scenario, you may want to look at Hystrix, given how easy it is to integrate into an existing Spring Boot application.

Have a look at how to integrate with it here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/.